# protobuf SerializeToArray rasie segmentation fault at InternalSerializeWithCachedSizesToArray

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, zeromq

To reuse protobuf messages, I firstly allocate it(msg_test,msg_proto), and then send it in an loop(for every loop do something like clear,set,send).

protobuf syntax = "proto3";

Call:

```
int i=0;
while(true){
    SendTestImprove(i++);
    usleep(1000*1000);
}
```

Function:

```
int SendTestImprove(int count)
{

    msg_test->Clear();
    msg_test->set_count(count);

    msg_proto->Clear();
    msg_proto->set_allocated_count(msg_test);
    msg_proto->set_tick_count(GetTickCount());

    zmq_msg_t zmsg;

    int size = msg_proto->ByteSize();

    int rc = zmq_msg_init_size(&zmsg,size);
    if(rc==0){
        try
        {
            rc = msg_proto->SerializeToArray(zmq_msg_data(&zmsg),size)?0:-1;
        }
        catch (google::protobuf::FatalException fe)
        {
            LOGFMTE("PbToZmq error: %s",fe.message().c_str());
        }
    }

    int  zsize = zmq_msg_size(&zmsg);

    rc = zmq_msg_send(&zmsg,m_pub,0);

    zmq_msg_close(&zmsg);

    LOGFMTD("zmq_msg_send,size=%d,zsize=%d",rc,zsize);
    return 0;
}
```

The error occurred when i=1, at the line :
rc = msg_proto->SerializeToArray(zmq_msg_data(&zmsg),size)?0:-1;

error info is like:
stopped:segmentation fault,at 
InternalWriteMessageNoVirtualToArray
,InternalSerializeWithCachedSizesToArray

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that you're assigning ownership of `msg_test` to `msg_proto` in each iteration of the loop, by calling `msg_proto->set_allocated_count(msg_test)`. The first time you do that it's fine, but then the next time through the loop when you call `set_allocated_count()` a second time, the proto will delete `msg_test` and reassign the now dangling pointer. The simplest solution is to avoid calling `set_allocated_count()` and instead just assign a copy of `msg_test`, like this:

```
*msg_proto->mutable_count() = msg_test;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, I check the code, and found msg_test was deleted multiple times. for every loop, both msg_proto->Clear() and msg_proto->set_allocated_count(msg_test) will delete msg_test. To reuse msg_test, I tried msg_proto->release_count() at the end of the loop, and it works now.